# GET http://localhost:3000/insert.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web-deployment

I'm a beginner at web dev, I'm currently working on a project, but the javascript file insert.js won't load. The html document, upload.html is inside the public folder, and the javascript is inside the main folder.
I used the following path to link the javascript file,

```
<script src= "../insert.js"></script>
```

But it didn't seem to work, so I then tried moving upload.html to the main folder, which is HR and I used the following code,

```
<script src = "/insert.js"></script>
```

And this didn't work either, so I then tried moving insert.js to the public folder, and used the same path as I have mentioned above, but, then I couldn't export variables to app.js which is located in the main HR directory.

[The image I have attached shows location of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7g71.png)

I don't get what could possibly cause this, I think I should mention this as well, but I got an error while running my javascript file in node. So I inserted the following code in node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/encoding.js:

```
const {TextDecoder, TextEncoder} = require("util");
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with my issue, but I thought I would just mention it.

Answer (score 1):

localhost can only access your public folder, so you have to move insert.js in the public folder and do:

```html
<script src = "index.js"></script>
```

Also if you have node modules in that javascript file it wont run because it can't run the modules and you would have to use a bundler for that js file like webpack, rollup or snowpack.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it, I just want to export one variable to the server side.